# AngularJs search still reads non existent data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I've come across something so bizarre. I had this below set up to read from a data.json file.  It should show up a list of people.  Instead it's ignoring the json file and is reading out non existing words!  I just want it to read from data.json.   Even if I delete "data.json" , the search function still prints out these words which don't exist.

[image]

As you can see from the photo, it's showing up a list of words that I DO NOT have stored anywhere in my code or on my server.  It's puzzling me.

```
<body ng-app="personApp">
    <div class="container">
        <header></header>
        <div ng-controller="PersonListCtrl">
            <div class="bar">Search:
                <input ng-model="query">
            </div>
            <ul class="">
                <li ng-repeat="person in persons | filter:query">{{person.name}}</li>
```

and

```
var personApp = angular.module('personApp', []);

personApp.controller('PersonListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('js/data.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.persons = data;
    })

});
```

data.json

```
  [{
            "name": "Mike Doe"
        }, {
            "name": "Jhon Doe"
        }, {
            "name": "Sam Doe"
        }, {
            "name": "Sam Doe"
        }, ];
```

Comment: We assure you that AngularJS does not populate its own data. You need to add console statements and find where it is coming from - it certainly should be coming from the `data.json` file, but maybe a different one. See the Network tab in Chrome developer tool and find which data.json is being read

Comment: Sounds like you may have another `data.json` file on your server? Reading your question I could not suppress a smile. This is weird.

Comment: I've checked the network tag.  It's not reading from any thing.  I've in fact deleted data.json..and checked for another one.  but the names keep appearing!

Also did egrep -r job2 etc...

They don't exist!

Comment: Deleted data.json...it still prints out those words!

*scratches head*

Answer (score 0):

Go to browser console -> Network.
Most probably you will see 304 status of your request, that means ajax request was cached by browser. Either clean cache, add query string to request etc.